# How can I get multiple input fields for my form that are unique?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a recipe app, where a user has the option of choosing pre existing ingredients and if the ingredient can't be found an option for the user to note down ingredient name on a input field. I want the form to have up to 5 input fields.

Iv seen similar questions asked but their solution has not worked.
[q1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583776/ruby-on-rails-multiple-input-fields-in-the-same-form-change-id-value)

[q2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754466/rails-only-save-record-if-fields-not-empty-for-nested-form)

Here's what I got so far, I'v tried two ways of doing it.

```
<%=f.fields_for :ingredients do |ing|%>
    <%= ing.label :name, "Enter ingredient name"%>
    <br>
    <%= ing.text_field :name%>
 <%end%>

 <%=f.fields_for :recipe_ingredients do |ri|%>
    <%=ri.fields_for :ingredient do |ing|%>
        <%=ing.label :name, "enter ing name"%>
        <%=ing.text_field :name%>
    <%end%>
 <%end%>
```

**recipes_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @recipe = Recipe.new
    5.times do 
        @recipe.recipe_ingredients.build.ingredient
    end
    5.times do 
        @recipe.ingredients.build
    end
end
```

**Associations**

A recipe has many ingredients through recipe_ingredients.

A ingredient has many recipes through recipe_ingredients.

---

I'm getting back only 1 input field for both cases, How can I do this?

Comment: use `f.fields_for @recipe.recipe_ingredients`

Comment: Do you know [this](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised)? It's always helpful.

Comment: I tried the @recipe.recipe_ingredients modification but still no change, and I was looking at that page iGian but I could not make it work for me, or at least I could not find the controller file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that both methods work. All I was missing was adding "accepts_nested_attributes_for" in my Recipe model class.